# JavaFX: ImageView is being displayed only when I use an absolute path... why?

Tags: xml, javafx, resources, scenebuilder

I'm using **JavaFX** with SceneBuilder on Intellij IDEA. I'm trying to display a simple png image in the login screen of my application. If I try to take the **relative path** (as showed below) **the picture won't be showed** (even if I don't get any error nor warning).

```
<ImageView
    fitHeight="87.0"
    fitWidth="91.0"
    pickOnBounds="true"
    preserveRatio="true">
    <image>
        <Image
            url="@../../res/logo.png" />
    </image>
</ImageView>
```

However, if I try with an **absolute path instead it works**.

```
<Image
    url="file:/home/username/Workspaces/IdeaProjects/MyProject/res/logo.png" />
```

Since I'm working on this project with a group and I'm sharing it with git, I absolutely need the path to be relative. How to solve this issue?

**Notice that** If I insert a relative path that brings to a non-existent resource I get an error! So the IDE correctly recognizes the path, but somehow can't display properly the picture when it's a relative path.

Comment: Did you try `@../../res/logo.png`? Furthermore are you sure the `res` directory is below the classpath root and not just one of the classpath roots? (I do no work with Intelij, so I'm not sure how projects are organized in this IDE...)

Comment: @fabian thanks for your comment! Oops, I will fix my post immediately: yes, I was using the `@`, I just removed it while copying it here on stackoverflow! And yes: I'm sure about the path: right below the root of the project I have `res` and `src`, and I'm working in the `/src/login` folder

Comment: Usually the `src` part is not part of the paths after the project is build. If the same happens to the resources the correct path should be `@../login.png`

Comment: What's important is not the location of the resources in the source code folder, but their location in the build or output folder (or jar file, if you build a jar file). The resources are, after all, loaded at runtime. Obviously those layouts are related, but exactly how they are related (i.e. how the various resources are deployed) is determined by your IDE and project settings. @fabian tells you what the default settings would give you (in most IDEs; I don't know IntelliJ), but the way to troubleshoot this is to open a file browser and look in the build folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this with IntelliJ and got it working. I suggest you to do the following:

- In IntelliJ go to File -> Project Structure...
- Under Modules select your res folder and add it as "Resources" folder.
- Click Ok, and change the path of your image to "/logo.png" in the fxml.

Image as follows for better explanation ;)
[image]